# Fatal error when compiling gtk3 app: glib.h not found

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, glib

I was trying to compile the [gtk3 example program](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) and I am constantly getting an error.

I have been searching google for about two hours and I cant find a solution for this.

Command passed:

```
g++ -m64 -std=c++17 ./src/gtkbuildtest.cpp -o ./debug/gtkbuildtest `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 gtk+-3.0`
```

Error thrown:

```
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:30,
             from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
             from ./src/globalincludes.hpp:18,
             from ./src/gtkbuildtest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkconfig.h:13:10: fatal error: glib/glib.h: No such file or directory
#include <glib/glib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Output of pkg-config:

```
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

System Version:

Ubuntu 18.10

I don't know why glib wont link properly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please add an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. what exactly you try to compile.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but may be `#include <glib.h>` (instead of `#include <glib/glib.h>`) will help you.
(glib.h are not in glib directory).

Comment: glib.h is in the correct directory, and pkg-config is outputting the include directories and search paths.

Comment: @Mutaru As pointed out by @guest, you **must** use `#include <glib.h>`, it is not an option. See [any section](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#glib-String-Utility-Functions.includes) of the GLib reference manual for examples.